# Render nested JSON data to razor page based on the user language (asp.net core razor pages)

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-core, razor

I created a simple ***Asp.net Core Razor Pages Web App*** with `.resx` files localization.

Now, I would want to render nested JSON data to the razor page, based on the user language. (Like `Tools.en.json` for English and `Tools.ru.json` to Russian)

Here's the nested JSON file:

```json
[
    // Category Object
    {
        "name": "Meteorology",
        "tools": [
            // Tool Object
            {
                "name": "Temperature Converter"
            }, {
                "name": "Wind Speed Calculator"
            }
        ]
    }, 
    // Category Object
    {
        "name": "Math",
        "tools": [
            // Tool Object
            {
                "name": "Simple Calculator"
            }, {
                "name": "Scientific Calculator"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

So basically There are *Categories* which are collections with a name and an array of tools. *Tools* is an array of objects with a name.

## My question is:

How can I render localized JSON data to the Razor Page, based on the user's current language?

This is an example of how it should be rendered:

```html
<div> <!-- Category -->
Meteorology

<div> <!-- Tools -->

  <div> <!-- Tool -->
    Temperature Converter
  </div>
  <div> <!-- Tool -->
    Wind Speed Calculator
  </div>

</div>

</div>

<div> <!-- Category -->
Math

<div> <!-- Tools -->

  <div> <!-- Tool -->
    Simple Calculator
  </div>
  <div> <!-- Tool -->
    Scientific Calculator
  </div>

</div>

</div>
```

My Startup.cs

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization.Routing;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationModels;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Rewrite;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using Website.Middlewares;
using Website.Services;

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor;

namespace Website
{

    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddRazorPages();

            services.AddControllers();

            services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");

            services
                .Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
                {
                    // var supportedCultures =
                    //     new List<CultureInfo> {
                    //         new CultureInfo("en"),
                    //         new CultureInfo("ru")
                    //     };

                    var supportedCultures = Services.CommonLocalizationService.SupportedCultures;

                    options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en");
                    options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
                    options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;

                    options.RequestCultureProviders.Insert(0, new CustomRequestCultureProvider(context =>
                    {
                        string defaultLang;

                        if (context.Request.Host.Host == "www.localhost")
                        {
                            return Task.FromResult(default(ProviderCultureResult));
                        }

                        var subdomain = Regex
                            .Replace(context.Request.Host.Host, @"www|" + "localhost", String.Empty)
                            .Split(".")
                            .Where(x => x != String.Empty).ToArray()[0];

                        if (supportedCultures.Contains(new CultureInfo(subdomain)))
                        {
                            defaultLang = subdomain;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // context.Response.Redirect("https://en.localhost:5001");

                            return Task.FromResult(default(ProviderCultureResult));
                        }

                        return Task.FromResult(new ProviderCultureResult(defaultLang, defaultLang));
                    }));
                });

            services.AddMvc().AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix)
            .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization();

            services.AddSingleton<Services.CommonLocalizationService>();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");

                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseWwwRedirection(); // Custom middleware

            app.UseStatusCodePages();
            app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/StatusPages/Status{0}");

            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            var localizationOptions = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>().Value;
            app.UseRequestLocalization(localizationOptions);

            app
                .UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
                {
                    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
                    endpoints.MapControllers();
                });
        }
    }
}
```

`.net version: net5.0`

Comment: the user language should be present in the request (either via request header, route data, query string or derived from the user id). Then you map it to the corresponding `json` file. Next load the file into some dictionary (exposed via some localizing service). The razor page just consumes that service by passing the keys (predefined) appropriately to get the translated texts.